# How to spot all $tickers in string?

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

```
$MRK - Merck - ($AAPL, $MSFT, $F) having day $AA! like $P and me :)
```

Although it's jibberish, it shows my problem. I want to scan for all words starting with a dollar-sign ($) and check them against a pre-defined list of tickers. If there's a match,  replace them with a label ({TICKER}), as follows:

```
{TICKER} - Merck - ({TICKER}, {TICKER},{TICKER}) having a day {TICKER}! like 
{TICKER} an me :)
```

I now use this function:

```
function _process_tickers($string) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT symbol FROM us_stocks");
  while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $tickers[] = ' $' . $row->symbol . ' ';
  }
  return str_replace($tickers, ' {TICKER} ', $tweet);
}
```

Problem: this only catches tickers that are surrounded by spaces (this $AA is surrounded by spaces) but not other situations like (this ticker has only a space in in front $AA) or (this one is surrounded by commas: my,$AA, ticker). But also two tickers right after each other (happy with $AA$XOM) - should become (happy with {TICKER}{TICKER}). How do I cath all these possible situations?

Comment: And on the eighth day the great processor in the sky created **regular expressions**. And he looked at what he had created, and it was good. You'll want [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for anything more complex than simple string replacement. Welcome to the world of pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
preg_replace('/\$[A-Z]+/', '{TICKER}', $tweet);
```

Comment: Thank! For my information, If you look at Dutchie432's answer (and the comments below), would using a regex have any advantage that I'm not seeing right now?

Comment: @Reveller: You don't even have to query the database at all to use it.

Comment: One question: I would have expected preg_replace('/\$[A-Z]+/', '{TICKER:$1}', $tweet); would return the matched pattern as {TICKER:MRK} for instance, but instead $1 returns nothing? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Reveller: You don't have any groups. Change it to `preg_replace('/\$([A-Z]+)/', '{TICKER:$1}', $tweet);`

Answer (score 1):

What's the downside of changing this code

```
 $tickers[] = ' $' . $row->symbol . ' ';
```

to this?

```
 $tickers[] = '$' . $row->symbol;
```

Doing so will make this change regardless of what comes before or after the ticker.

Comment: `$AAPL $A` -> `{TICKER}APL {TICKER}`

Comment: First I though: what stupid of me not to just think of what Dutchie432 said. Then I saw the same problem. But it can be solved by ordering ticker by length desc: $AAPL $A => {TICKER} {TICKER} :) Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough.. If that's a valid concern, I can see the `fail`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are probably looking for the `\b` word boundary</strike> If the "tickers" will always just be a string of capital letters, this should suffice:

```
<?php
$str = '$MRK - Merck - ($AAPL, $MSFT, $F) having day $AA! like $P and me :)';
echo preg_replace('#\$[A-Z]+#', '{TICKER}', $str), "\n";
```

Output:

```
{TICKER} - Merck - ({TICKER}, {TICKER}, {TICKER}) having day {TICKER}! like {TICKER} and me :)
```

Comment: `\b` doesn't make any difference when you have `[A-Z]+`.

Comment: @minitech: Yeah, it's still early. :-)